# Deploying JS projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, dependencies, web-deployment

I would like you to share your way of deploying complicated JS projects, where `Grunt` or `Gulp` are used.

For example, `grunt build` command concats css, js files, puts minified bower dependencies into `dist` folder. As far as i know, we should not store build results in version control repo, shouldn't we? Also, development environment is not needed on production server.

That is why flow like: `git push production`, and then `grunt build` on production server, then restarting it is not a good practice, isn't it?

The purpose o question is to find out, how should I deploy complicated JS projects when:

- Building is necessary.
- Building should not be done on production server.(Or it is a normal practice?)
- Build results should not be indexed by version control system.
- Deployment should not be done manually.

Comment: *"we should not store build results in version control repo, shouldn't we"* Depends. Some even go as far as storing the node-modules folder in their repository to make deployment far faster and less likely to have conflict problems (though that could also be fixed with shrinkwrap) For some module types it is common to store the build folder in the repository, for example, js libraries commonly used in the browser. Storing the build folder makes importing with bower easier.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sure, some do. But is it a right way? As far as I know, in java or c/c++ world it is not a common practice to store binaries in version control system's repository.

Comment: Right/Wrong in this case is just an opinion. I would say it's wrong to include node_modules in the repo because shrinkwrap is available, but, including it simplifies the deployment process thus possibly preventing bugs in the deploy process. Pick your poison.